# Python Plotly animation_frame Slider Only Showing First Year Data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plotly

I'm having trouble getting my animation_frame to work for my reservoir data. I'm trying to set it up so that the user can use to slider to display all algae results for the selected year. It displays 2019 data (the first year in my dataset) just fine, but when I move the slider to 2020, 2021, 2022, or 2023, no data appears even though it's definitely in my dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

# Read the Excel spreadsheet into a Pandas DataFrame:
df = pd.read_excel('Master Reservoir Data.xlsx')

# Add a Year column and extract the Year from the Date column, then sort by year
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year.astype(str)
df = df.sort_values(by='Year')

#Filter the DataFrame for the "Rockwell" location
filtered_df = df[(df['Location'] == 'Rockwell Dam/Pier')]

#Create a scatter plot using Plotly Express, animate slider by year
fig = px.scatter(filtered_df, x='Date', y='Depth (m)',
                 title='Blue-Green Algae Profiles at Rockwell Dam, YSI Sonde, All Depths',
                 color='Blue-Green Algae (cells/mL)',
                 color_continuous_scale=['green', 'yellow', 'red'],
                 range_color=(0,10000), animation_frame='Year')
fig.update_layout(yaxis_autorange='reversed')
fig.show()
```

I thought the data was not sorted correctly, so I tried sorting it by year, but that didn't seem to help. I also tried to mimic this tutorial (https://plotly.com/python/animations/), but my animation does not seem to be working the same way as the tutorial and I can't find the key difference.

Here's a snippet of filtered_df:

| Date | Year | Location | Depth (m) | Blue-Green Algae (cells/mL) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8/25/2019 | 2019 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 6.0 | 10000.0 |
| 8/25/2019 | 2019 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 5.0 | 11140.0 |
| 8/25/2019 | 2019 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 0.0 | 8000.0 |
| 9/15/2020 | 2010 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 1.0 | 10900.0 |
| 7/25/2020 | 2010 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 2.0 | 11200.0 |
| 6/10/2020 | 2020 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 2.0 | NaN |
| 5/25/2021 | 2021 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 3.0 | NaN |
| 4/13/2021 | 2021 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 4.0 | NaN |
| 5/2/2022 | 2022 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 5.0 | NaN |
| 8/20/2022 | 2022 | Rockwell Dam/Pier | 0.0 | 560.0 |

Comment: example of the data that exists in the `Master Reservoir Data.xlsx` file ?

Comment: I updated the post with a snippet of the data. Do you think it has something to do with the NaN values?

Comment: when i run the code, i see data for every year.   However, the x-axis (data) does not change.

Comment: Oh, interesting. Do you know how to make the x-axis update with the slider?

Comment: If you want to set the x-axis to date and animate based on year, you cannot do this with express. You must use a graph object and create an animation frame with the data extracted by year. See [this](https://plotly.com/python/animations/#using-a-slider-and-buttons)

Comment: If you change `x='Date'` to `x='Year'` in the current code, you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

okay, so i slightly modify the code (to be immediately reproducible).

i also amended `x=Year` as per `r-beginners` comment.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.io as pio

from io import StringIO

data = """
Date,Year,Location,Depth (m),Blue-Green Algae (cells/mL)
8/25/2019,2019,Rockwell Dam/Pier,6.0,10000.0
8/25/2019,2019,Rockwell Dam/Pier,5.0,11140.0
8/25/2019,2019,Rockwell Dam/Pier,0.0,8000.0
9/15/2020,2010,Rockwell Dam/Pier,1.0,10900.0
7/25/2020,2010,Rockwell Dam/Pier,2.0,11200.0
6/10/2020,2020,Rockwell Dam/Pier,2.0,NaN
5/25/2021,2021,Rockwell Dam/Pier,3.0,NaN
4/13/2021,2021,Rockwell Dam/Pier,4.0,NaN
5/2/2022,2022,Rockwell Dam/Pier,5.0,NaN
8/20/2022,2022,Rockwell Dam/Pier,0.0,560.0
"""

# Use StringIO to convert the string data into a file-like object
data_io = StringIO(data)

# Read the data into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv(data_io)

# Add a Year column and extract the Year from the Date column, then sort by year
df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.year.astype(str)
df = df.sort_values(by='Year')

#Filter the DataFrame for the "Rockwell" location
filtered_df = df[(df['Location'] == 'Rockwell Dam/Pier')]

#Create a scatter plot using Plotly Express, animate slider by year
fig = px.scatter(filtered_df, x='Year', y='Depth (m)',
                 title='Blue-Green Algae Profiles at Rockwell Dam, YSI Sonde, All Depths',
                 color='Blue-Green Algae (cells/mL)',
                 color_continuous_scale=['green', 'yellow', 'red'],
                 range_color=(0,10000), animation_frame='Year')

# Update the layout to reverse the y-axis and set the x-axis range
fig.update_layout(yaxis_autorange='reversed')

fig.show()
```

the result looks like this:
[image]

I can move the slider and the x-axis (in my vscode editor) to see all the data.